# Mass mailing links changed

Tags: odoo-11, mailing

I have a problem with the links inserted in my mass mailing on Odoo 11 Community.

The links that should point to external sites are modified and point to my Odoo domain.
For exemple, https://github.com/odoo is changed to https://my-odoo-domain.com/odoo
But when I use the test button, links are good.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

It was due to the absence of the link.tracker sequence which disappeared after the migration of the database.
I recreated it and it works again.